# Javascript - PHP Websocket - Getting User IP Address

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I'm trying to make a game.

However, I can't get the user ip address on the php side.

I am using plain websocket.

I tried the following codes but it doesn't give what I want. The server gives the ip address.

JAVASCRIPT

```
websocket = new WebSocket("wss://site.com/game_play/"); 
websocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
websocket.onopen = function(event) { 
    
    var send = {
        type: "sign",
        oauth: g_oauth,
        room: g_room,
    };
    websocket.send(binary_encode(send));
}
.....
```

PHP

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => 1, 'usec' => 0));
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array('sec' => 1, 'usec' => 0));
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);

socket_listen($socket);
.....
```

APACHE

```
ProxyPass /game_play/ ws://site.com:8090/server.php
ProxyPassReverse /game_play/ ws://site.com:8090/server.php
```

socket_getsockname, socket_getpeername

I tried some functions but unsuccessful. Because the server gives the ip address. I am trying to get user ip address.

Comment: Does $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] work? Not sure how this will behave with sockets as I haven't used php w/them.

Comment: @jshrc $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] not working in websocket.

Comment: _"I tried some functions but unsuccessful."_ perhaps the wrong functions? or perhaps because that were wild guesses? Maybe a remote address with Websockets works differently than your understanding what a remote address is?

Comment: @CoinAnalyzer: Not working? How does it looks like when $_SERVER is not working? Does PHP crash? Is it undefined offset?

Comment: @hakre Maybe.. How can I get out of this dead end? :)

Comment: Darn, can you `var_dump($_SERVER)` and see what's in there?

Comment: Looking at the docs for `socket_getsockname` the second parameter is passed by reference and should contain the remote IP if the function returns true. 

`$address = '';`
`socket_getsockname($socket, $address); `

$address should have your remote ip since it's passed by reference. The function changes its value.

Comment: @jshrc $_SERVER is for http requests. this is a websocket.

I'm booting over SSH. Example: php xx.php

Comment: Got it. Like I said, I don't have any experience with php sockets, just php, and sockets w/node.

Comment: Wrong person buddy @hakre

Comment: @hakre I don't understand why you're being aggressive. I wrote all the codes myself, but the ip address issue is a complete mystery.

Comment: @CoinAnalyzer: Sure you've wrote it yourself, but where did you get the idea from to use these functions? As I misread you that you wouldn't have any experience - perhaps you have indeed! I'd like to get a better impression and ask for context. No idea how you can think this is aggressive. Just to make it clear: You don't have to provide debugging details, just the minimal example to reproduce your issue. More context in the help section.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-getsockname.php) you may need to use `socket_accept()` instead of `socket_connect()`:

> Note: socket_getsockname() should not be used with AF_UNIX sockets
> created with socket_connect(). Only sockets created with
> socket_accept() or a primary server socket following a call to
> socket_bind() will return meaningful values.

Edit: wrong function called, should be socket_getpeername()

Either way, the second param in socket_getpeername() is passed by reference and will contain the client IP if the socket is good:

```
<?php 
....
socket_listen($socket);

$address = '';
socket_getpeername($socket, $address); //$address is passed by reference and will contain the remote IP.
```

Comment: $socket_new = socket_accept($this->server);
socket_getsockname($socket_new, $address);
echo "#$socket_new - $address  CONNECTED!\n";

Not client ip. Server ip.

socket_connect trying...

Comment: My bad, it should be socket_getpeername is for the client.  socket_getsockname  is for the local side. Edited my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the server gives the ip address. I still can't get the user ip address.

`$socket_new = socket_accept($this->server);

socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip);
echo "#$socket_new - $ip CONNECTED!\n";
`

Comment: You're not running this locally right? The php is running on a totally different machine? (Sorry, I have to ask as the docs make it pretty clear this would give the remote ip)

Comment: You could try `socket_recvfrom()` and get the IP after the initial connection is made?

`$size=socket_recvfrom($socket,$input,65535,0,$ipaddress,$port);`
`echo "Received [$input] ($size bytes) from IP $ipaddress Port $port\n";`

Comment: No. I'm starting the websocket server via php file.

SSH COMMAND: php xxx.php

Then I go to my site with the browser. Then I look at the php output over ssh.

Comment: Sorry, your answer isn't very clear/I'm not understanding. The php script is running on a totally different computer than the computer you're browsing on?

Comment: I think we succeed. I detected a ip in the headers section.

X-Forwarded-For:

So how do I just get the ip adress ? ?

Comment: You could do a regex match for the ip? `preg_match('#[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}#', $headers, $matches);` and the ip should be in `$matches` then.

Not sure what else will be in the headers with all the socket stuff so might need to stick 'X-Forwarded-For: ' after the first # to only match that IP if more than one is sent.

Comment: Big waste of time.

`$header = socket_read($socket_new, 4096);
$this->handshake($header,$socket_new,$this->host,$this->port);
print_r($header);

X-Forwarded-For: XX`

The ip information is in the headers. Now there are doubts.

How can we trust the ip address in the header information?

Comment: Did you try `socket_recvfrom()`? 

`$size=socket_recvfrom($socket,$input,65535,0,$ipaddress,$port);` `echo "Received [$input] ($size bytes) from IP $ipaddress Port $port\n";`

Comment: Yes, However, the return value of $ip address is still the server ip address. The ip address in the header information is correct, but.

Comment: Hmmm...I don't know what else to try. As you noticed, the headers could be spoofed by a malicious user. If the script is running on a different machine one of these functions should be returning a different IP than your local computer. Maybe there's a bug in the library?  Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: One last question. Could this be caused by apache proxypass or proxy server? Because we need to do a reverse proxy to use WSS.

Comment: Probably? That would explain the forwarded for headers. If the proxy is running on the same server as the php script I'd say more than likely that's the case then.